# Answering and ending skype calls using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, skype

I am trying to use VB.net to answer and end Skype calls on button presses. I have tried this:

```
 Public Sub oSkype_CallStatus(pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call, Status As 
SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus) Handles oSkype.CallStatus
    If Status = SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus.clsInProgress Then
        pCall.Finish()
    End If
 End Sub
```

Which works great but I'm trying to end a call on a button press and not depending on the call status. I have tried calling this method when a button is pressed, but I am not sure what to put as the parameter for pCall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype is no longer supporting this API so it has lost some functionality. In order to end and answer calls I am sending keys via c# to Skype the corresponds to the hot keys that I have set in Skype. So I set Alt PGUP to answer a call and in code I send

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%(PGUP)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean that changes value when you press the button. :)

```
Dim PressedEnd As Boolean = False

Private Sub ButtonEnd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonEnd.Click
    PressedEnd = True
End Sub

Public Sub oSkype_CallStatus(pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call, Status As SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus) Handles oSkype.CallStatus
    If Status = SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus.clsInProgress AndAlso PressedEnd = True Then
        PressedEnd = False
        pCall.Finish()
    End If
End Sub
```

Same goes for answering.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried this but when I press the end button it does not end the current call. It actually ends the following call I make. So if I press the end button the current call will continue until I manually press the stop button in Skype, then when I try to start the next call it ends immediately after the call is answered. Any thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: I will try ro recreate this when I get the time.

Comment: I don't know for sure about this, but since you probably know Skype isn't fully supporting it's API anymore. It could be a problem due to that. I've had problems myself with my Skype API application. I will still try to find a solution for you though